# Load a PDF document from remote server into base64 encoded data

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cors, filereader

Is there any any option available to load a PDF from a website (e.g. http://mywebsite.com/mydoc.pdf) and read it into base64 (or) binary data using javascript. The XHR (ajax) request not helps me due to cross domain scripting restrictions. The HTML5 FileReader API works with user file **input** control. I could not think of any other option. Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is the server one that you control?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a fixed server to control. My HTML(only) application suppose to load PDF from any given web link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said there are cross domain restrictions that prevent you from downloading any old file from another domain. There are a couple of ways round this.

If the server you're downloading from supports CORS requests then you should be able to download the file as a binary object. If you're downloading from a server you control then you could update it to support CORS requests.

If CORS support on the originating server isn't an option then you could create a proxy on your server to download the PDF and pass it on to the client. Either host it on the same domain or make sure it supports CORS requests from your domain.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately i don't have a fixed server to control. My HTML(only) application suppose to load PDF from any given web link. Where i can find more details/example on this Proxy method?

Comment: The only way to do this purely client side would be to use something like a Chrome extension that wasn't subject to the same security policies. Or you could find some cloud service that would act as your CORS proxy. I couldn't find any with a quick Google, but it's the type of thing that may be out there. Alternatively you could host something for free on a service like Heroku.